# Use of instance variables in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

**Working through Rails Tutorial 3rd Edition by Michael Hartl: Ch 8 Log in, Log out**

I need help understanding why in the session_controller we use a regular 'user' variable while in the users_controller we use an '@user' instance variable.

I noticed that in the session_controller, we use

```
def create
    user = User.find_by...
```

whereas in the users_controller, we use

```
 def create
   @user = User.new...
```

Michael states, "The main difference between the session form and the signup form is that we have no Session model, and hence no analogue for the @user variable..." referring to this:

```
form_for(@user)
```

from the users view versus

```
form_for(:session, url: login_path)
```

from the session view.

Is this related? I am still not understanding this.  Please let me know if I need to be more clear or specific.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
  user = User.find_by...
```

In this case, `user` is a local variable. It is just being used within the same method.

```
def create
  @user = User.new...
```

Here, `@user` is an instance variable, attached to the `UsersController`, and by making it an instance variable, it is made accessible in the corresponding views.

So if you look at any views related to users under `app/views/users`, there will be a reference to `@user`. Nothing of that sort is done in the views related to sessions (i.e. view files under `app/views/sessions` folder)

Answer (score 0):

Variables user and @user has different scopes

user variable available between words def end

```
def create
  user = User.new
  print user
end
create 
print user 
NameError: undefined local variable ...
```

you cannot use user variable outside the block of method definition, but if you use variable like @user you can

```
def create
  @user = User.new
  print @user
end
create 
print @user 
#<User:0x007fe1d25596d0>=> nil
```

So only @user variable can be used in views.
Author use local variable user in session_controller, because there no needs to use this variable in view and he use @user on users_controller because if user validation fails it will render form  form_for(@user) with values that user entered before submit. So user do not have to fill all form fields again, he need just fix only wrong fields

Answer (score 0):

> I am still not understanding this. Please let me know if I need to be more clear or specific.

Let's try to understand how all these things are working:

In `users_controller`, you are instantiating a blank user object by `@user = User.new`, which you will be using in your registration form. The reason of doing this is, if you instantiate a new object and pass that object as an argument in form, rails will automatically call create method of `users_controller`. Things will be done because of Rails RESTful resource route.

During `#create`,

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

is equivalent to:

```
<%= form_for @user, as: :user, url: users_path, html: { class: "new_user", id: "new_user" } do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

On the other hand, if you instantiate an old record like `@user = User.find(...)`, rails will call `#update` method of `users_controller` when you submit the form.

During `#update`,

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

is equivalent to:

```
<%= form_for @user, as: :user, url: user_path(@user), method: :patch, html: { class: "edit_user", id: "edit_user_1" } do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

So, now why instance variable is not used in `sessions_controller` `#create` action? Okay, if you instantiate an `@user` object and use that in login form like what you did in registration form, it will call `#create` action of `users_controller` instead of `#create` action of `sessions_controller`.

This is why in login form `form_for(:session, url: login_path)` is used. You will receive a `Hash` with `:session` key in it and since submitting url is explicitly told, that is `login_path`, the login information will submitted to `#create` action of `sessions_controller`.

Hope now things are making sense.

Comment: _"So, now why instance variable is not used in sessions_controller #create action? Okay, if you instantiate an @user object and use that in login form like what you did in registration form, it will call #create action of users_controller instead of #create action of sessions_controller."_

Comment: Are you saying that the @user instance variable defined in UsersController is available in forms outside of views/users/ ?